# ¿Como puedo cambiar el fondo de unos JTextField y que estos se cambien de color uno a uno?

Tags: java

Haciendo una aplicacion en Java usando Netbeans necesito que unos `JTextField` se cambie de color uno a uno con forme se van leyendo, lo unico que he logrado hacer es que todos se cambien de color pero no se muestra la accion por asi decirlo, he intentado hacerlo con *timer* pero no lo he logrado

```
JTextField[] W;
W = new JTextField[9];
W[0]=txtT1C00;
W[1]=txtT1C01;
W[2]=txtT1C02;
W[3]=txtT1C10;
W[4]=txtT1C11;
W[5]=txtT1C12;
W[6]=txtT1C20;
W[7]=txtT1C21;
W[8]=txtT1C22;
```

aqui defino los paneles de texto y luego con un ciclo `for` hago que se cambien de color uno a uno el `TU.length` es otra matriz que es de 3*3, si cambia de color pero no logro hacer la animacion,

```
int e;
e=0;
for (int x = 0; x < TU.length; x++) { //x genera el moviemiento en las filas
  for (int y = 0; y < TU[x].length; y++) {//y genera el movimiento
    W[e].setBackground(Color.RED);
    e=e+1;
  }
}
```

Agradeceria sugerencias de con que libreria puedo hacerlo o con que metodo muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar *Threads* para lo que quieres realizar simplemente tu `class Frame` tiene que implementar `Runnable` y con eso podrías sobre escribir el metodo `run()` aqui puedes usar `sleep()` para hacer las pausas, algo asi:

```
public void run() {
  jTextField1.setBackground(Color.red);
  try {
    Thread.sleep(500 );//Milisegundos
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
  jTextField2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
}
```

En el momento que deseas empezar el hilo solo  debes Instanciar un nuevo `Thread` y ejecutar su funcion `start()`.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(this);
thread.start();
```